# get rate for a temporary shipment

Tags: easypost

I am trying to use easy post API and I would like to get shipment quote without creating then? (temorary shipment).
Idea is customer wants to have a shipment quote but he have no take decision to buy then and maybe he will buy then with another api.

What is the correct way to process this with easy post API?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Shipment object and get rates without purchasing a label. You'll see in step4 of the [Getting Started Guide](https://www.easypost.com/getting-started#step4) that the last step is to purchase a rate.

While you're developing, we recommend developing your purchase flow using test mode (use your test api key), so that no real labels are purchased.